# read excel and parse in different manner

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a excel, but don`t know how to parse this data frame in a specific manner, where I need to print column name along with data inside. Consider below scenario...

this is how excel looks like

[image]

and the output be like

```
this is string,abc,klm,column-4,13
this is string,abc,klm,column-5,12
this is string,abc,klm,column-6,15
this is string,def,klm,column-4,13
this is string,def,klm,column-5,12
this is string,def,klm,column-6,15
this is string,ghi,klm,column-4,13
this is string,ghi,klm,column-5,12
this is string,ghi,klm,column-6,15
this is string,abc,nop,column-4,13
this is string,abc,nop,column-5,12
this is string,abc,nop,column-6,15
this is string,def,nop,column-4,13
this is string,def,nop,column-5,12
this is string,def,nop,column-6,15
this is string,ghi,nop,column-4,13
this is string,ghi,nop,column-5,12
this is string,ghi,nop,column-6,15
```

Answer (score 0):

explode function will help, once you convert the comma separated values into the list, followed by melt

using df.to_csv(), you can export that as a CSV file (not shown in result)

```
df
```

```
    column-1    column-2    column-3    column-4    column-5    column-6
0   this is a string    abcd,def, ghi   klm,nop     13  12  15
```

```
df['column-2'] = df['column-2'].str.split(',')
df['column-3'] = df['column-3'].str.split(',')

df=df.explode('column-2')
df=df.explode('column-3')
df = df.melt(id_vars=['column-1','column-2','column-3'] )
df
```

```
column-1    column-2    column-3    variable    value
0   this is a string    abcd    klm     column-4    13
1   this is a string    abcd    nop     column-4    13
2   this is a string    def     klm     column-4    13
3   this is a string    def     nop     column-4    13
4   this is a string    ghi     klm     column-4    13
5   this is a string    ghi     nop     column-4    13
6   this is a string    abcd    klm     column-5    12
7   this is a string    abcd    nop     column-5    12
8   this is a string    def     klm     column-5    12
9   this is a string    def     nop     column-5    12
10  this is a string    ghi     klm     column-5    12
11  this is a string    ghi     nop     column-5    12
12  this is a string    abcd    klm     column-6    15
13  this is a string    abcd    nop     column-6    15
14  this is a string    def     klm     column-6    15
15  this is a string    def     nop     column-6    15
16  this is a string    ghi     klm     column-6    15
17  this is a string    ghi     nop     column-6    15
```